# boot from pendrive FREEBSD Mounting from cd9660 :/ dev/iso9660 error :/ dev/iso9660/FREEBSD_INSTALL failed with error 19

Tags: freebsd, installation, boot

I am trying to install FreeBSD from a pen drive.
But it returns an error on boot.

```
cd9660 :/dev/iso9660 error :/dev/iso9660/FREEBSD_INSTALL failed with error 19
```

and appears

```
mountroot>
```

command ?

```
List of GEOM managed disk devices:
    MSDOSFS/multiboot da0s1 da0 ada0
```

I've tried, but without success.

```
ufs:/dev/da0s1
ufs:/dev/da0
ufs:/dev/ada0
cd9660:/dev/da0s1
cd9660:/dev/da0
cd9660:/dev/ada0
```

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: 1) Are you sure you want to be on [sf] and not on [su]? 2) If I understand you correctly then installing works fine, but when you boot the new OS after it is installed then the bootloader can not the disk to mount / from ?

Comment: And to do the installation, the error appears. Not yet installed freebsd.

Comment: This is really something you should take up with the FreeBSD folks (politely please). If this is your first time using FreeBSD the EFNet `#FreeBSDHelp` IRC channel would be a good place to ask. At first glance however Kindule appears to be correct: You've somehow managed to screw up creating your installation media. Review the instructions in the handbook for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the message "MSDOSFS/mutilboot", so did you use grub2 for the installation? Have your ever see this article?

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/bsdinstall-pre.html#BSDINSTALL-INSTALLATION-MEDIA

The memory stick image has a img extension. You should use that for your installation. And use the command to wirte the image file to the Memory Stick.

```
dd if=FreeBSD-9.0-RELEASE-i386-memstick.img of=/dev/da0 bs=64k
```